# apt: how to be sure that a specific package gets installed/updated from specific repository and not from the default one?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, nginx

Due to personal preference I always install the package "NGINX" [from its specific PPA](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/#ubuntu-ppa). I want to be 100% sure that I'm actually installing  it from there, and not from the Ubuntu-provided repository.

How can I give it higher priority or, even better, disable the installation of the nginx package from the default repo?

Comment: Thanks @Ravexina , it looks like it does! I'm marking my own question as duplicate, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome :)